# Can Informatica's Stored Procedure Transformer process stored procedures that have multiple resultsets?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a stored procedure that returns two resultsets.  I know Informatica has a Stored Procedure Transformer, but I cannot find anywhere it is possible to handle a stored procedure that returns more than one resultset.

Is this an Informatica capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, I'm afraid. Informatica will not be able to 'guess' what to do with each dataset. 
In general, whatever it is that you need to do with the results, e.g. if you need to:

- join them, or
- use just one of them in a particular mapping, or
- switch between them with every run,

I'd recommend to wrap this stored procedure with another one, that would perform the logic required and return the appropriate result set.

Answer (score 1):

Informatica SP transformation can produce only return value not a result set as far as I am aware of.

The possible solution is, store the result-set data into a table/flat-file and use it as a source (either using SQ override or flat file source) in the following mapping

Comment: You're right. However, it is possible to use a Stored Procedure as a source, and get the result set right from it. You just need to put the SP call as SQL override on Source Qualifier.

Comment: Wow o didn't know that. Let me see how can I active it..thanks though!